# PHP encoding and obfuscation

Tags: php, encoding

I've been trying to understand what the code below is doing. On a fundamental level I understand what the decoding process is doing however, once arriving to the for loop, It becomes a bit confusing. Basically, I'm trying to take the below and write an appropriate encoder which will allow me to reuse the decoding routine below. I'm using this for the obfuscation of a PHP script.

Would anyone be so kind as to provide assistance in the area of taking the below and providing guidance on how I'd be able to write the reverse of this (an encoder) vs the decoding method provided?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
    $B_yhp='bCtyDEF7u+8SszsSu+kgCO5ydU+XgC8PCVdhu1jwM7cyDU6dY0V7URbSZ/';
    $L_qmfd=base64_decode($B_yhp);
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($L_qmfd); $i++)
    {
      $L_qmfd[$i]=chr(ord($L_qmfd[$i])^((91403)%256));
    }
    $Laz_ep=@gzinflate(strrev($L_qmfd));
    //Use $Lax_ep to generate a function IE: 
    //create_function('$runtime',$Laz_ep);
?>
```

Edited:

I've tried to create the encoder using the following but I believe I'm missing / doing something wrong. The CRC values don't end up matching and the php code doesn't successfully decode to it's original state so I know I'm clearly missing a step or overlooking something here.

```
<?php

    $hash = hash_file('crc32b', $argv[1]);
    $array = unpack('N', pack('H*', $hash));
    $crc32 = $array[1];
    printf("CRC: %u\n",$crc32);

    $content = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
    $content = strrev($content);
    $content = gzdeflate($content, 9);
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($content); $i++)
    {
        $content[$i]=chr( ord($content[$i])^((91403)%256));
    }
    $content=base64_encode($content);
    file_put_contents($argv[1]. ".packed",$content);
?>
```

Comment: strrev(), gzdeflate(), xor with same value and base64_encode() ... what's the problem?

Comment: Jack, thank you for that I've edited my question to include my attempt at the encoder however the CRC is failing I believe due to something I'm missing in the process.

Comment: Not sure how to help you further because the first code you've posted gives a data error at `gzinflate()` which is not surprising because you're doing XOR 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the `gzdeflate` and `strrev` in the wrong order. Do the `gzdeflate` first, then reverse the deflated `$content`.

```
<?php

    $hash = hash_file('crc32b', $argv[1]);
    $array = unpack('N', pack('H*', $hash));
    $crc32 = $array[1];
    printf("CRC: %u\n",$crc32);

    $content = file_get_contents($argv[1]);
    $content = gzdeflate($content, 9);         // Swapped these
    $content = strrev($content);               // two lines
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($content); $i++)
    {
        $content[$i]=chr( ord($content[$i])^((91403)%256));
    }
    $content=base64_encode($content);
    file_put_contents($argv[1]. ".packed",$content);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Kaivosukeltaja, that was exactly the problem! I can't believe I missed that...